# flex-shrink: 0 and white-space: wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace

I have a flexbox container with 2 columns. I want the columns to stack when there isn't room to display them both. I use the following html/css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div>Short content</div>
        <div>This is some longer content to show problem</div>
        <div>Short contetn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div>Short content</div>
        <div>This is some longer content to show problem</div>
        <div>Short contetn</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    /* grow, don't shrink */
}
```

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsdNS/

It seems that there is implicitally `white-space: nowrap` on the inner divs, but I don't want this. If I did want it surely I would specify it in my css. Is there a way to not wrap whitespace and then only wrap the columns if a single block of text with no whitespace is too big?

In practice I want to force it to wrap on some whitespace, but not others (I will use `<span>`s)

**EDIT** Here is a more real-world jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7g3U/1/

What I want is for the long div to wrap, but the short divs not to.

**EDIT 2** Here is what I want to achieve (works in chrome) http://plnkr.co/edit/Ppoe8xJrrbC16Y1vyWCD

Comment: Do I have to explicitally specify white-space: normal in the inner divs?

Comment: it may be the behavior of `flex-direction:row` (which is the default style), if somehow after stacking the columns into 1 column, you can change it to `flex-direction:column`, it will work as expected. If the `.container` fills the page's width, you can try using `@media` rule, otherwise using script is also acceptable.

Comment: I see no white-space:nowrap; behavior here , the long sentence will wrap when width becomes too short?  all 3 divs are stack inside .column, this is too a normal behavior. Do I misunderstand your problem ?

Comment: @GCyrillus How do I get white-space: wrap

Comment: When do you want the text to wrap and when do you want the columns to stack? If you specify a width for the column the text will wrap earlier, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AsdNS/1/

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for your comment - I guess I am also asking is this a problem with the spec: shouldn't we have the choice to wrap text or not? Since there is already a perfectly good css property for that. Maybe it could default to white-space nowrap and then you could change it manually if you so desire?

Comment: @Mathias I don't want to restrict myself to specific widths - I want to describe how I lay out the document and let the browser calculate the widths.

Comment: ?? defaut for white-space is **wrap** and this is what happens here ? You only need to write the rule when earlier you did set another value. Block elements by defaut,sprays on whole width/horizontal space avalaible and text flows in it. I really do not understand what you are asking for or what probleme you do have here :(

Comment: @GCyrillus suppose when the 2 columns become 1 column, here is what he wants http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/AsdNS/4/ (try resizing the window as small as possible, you'll see the text is wrapped). Also try the original demo to see how it treats the text.

Comment: on both , text wraps for me , except for the initila behavior, one is row the other is column. what browser and OS are you testing on ?

Comment: I don't think it involves the OS here, for browser I'm using Opera latest version. Also I think I've found the answer here, it's simple enough, just set `flex:1 1 auto` (instead of `flex:1 0 auto1`), check this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/AsdNS/6/

Comment: @GCyrillus are you sure your demo has `flex:1 0 auto` not `flex:1 1 auto`? because `flex:1 0 auto` should not work I think.

Comment: @GCyrillus looks like you tested it on ***FireFox***, I've tested it on all major browsers now, only ***FireFox*** works with `flex: 1 0 auto`, all the others don't. `flex:1 1 auto` work for all browsers.

Comment: the second value in `flex` is for `flex-shrink`, so how could it shrink with the value `0`? looks like ***FireFox*** implemented flex-box layout in a wrong way.

Comment: hey, flex:1 0 auto; doesn't actually work in FF , so this is why i did not notice that.  i never use(d) this value  for flex-shrink. surprised here by IE11 :)

Comment: @GCyrillus not sure what version of FF you are using, I've tested on FF latest version and here is the snapshot http://i.imgur.com/jqESyDW.png You can see `flex:1 0 auto` does work on FF v 29

Comment: @KingKing I think `flex-shrink: 0` means that the flex boxes shouldn't shrink. In your image they do shrink causing the words to wrap. `flex: 1 0 auto` and `flex: 1 1 auto` will produce different results in chrome. Firefox seem to ignore `flex-shrink`.

Comment: @Mathias the image I posted to show that FF treats the `flex: 1 0 auto` in a different way, while all the other major browsers don't treat it that way. I've tested the code on all the major browsers and see that `flex: 1 1 auto` does work for all ***with the same result***. No difference here. Ignoring `flex-shrink` is a bug, why ignore it? and the last I think you are a fan of ***FireFox***, that's all.

Comment: @KingKing , thks, I run FF 29.01 under W7 same result as you, it bugs :) on flex-shrink:0;

Comment: @KingKing I was trying to say that I don't think `flex: 1 0 auto`/`flex-shrink: 0` works in Firefox. It treats it just like `flex: 1 1 auto` which is wrong. I thought you were saying that the behavior in FF was correct.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. I know this is an edge case, but maybe one that will come up for other people. @KingKing your fiddle stacks before it wraps, whereas I want to wrap before I stack. I'll do a more fully fledged example so I can show how my layout will look.

Comment: I've added another jsfiddle - it shows a layout for a responsive contact panel. Just like to note that I'm using chromium derrivative - ff doesn't work at all.

Comment: @derekdreery is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/W7g3U/2/

Comment: It looks like you'll get desired behavior by changing `flex: 1 0 auto;` to `flex: 1 1 50%;`. You specified that you don't want to give a width. Why? That said, I'm not sure why auto doesn't give the same behavior as when 50% is specified. I'd think that these two should behave the same: http://jsfiddle.net/4sz56/, http://jsfiddle.net/4sz56/1/ but they don't.

Comment: I'll knock something up in JS to show what I want.

Comment: I've added a plunker to show what I want to achieve (EDIT 2). It had a bug in it I've just fixed.